# Get the process references child related to process reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table:

```
Runing_process   PROCESS_Reference  
Parent_process   Process1
Parent_process   Process2
Parent_process   MYTABLE
Process1         MYTABLE
Process2         Process3
Process2         Process4
Process3         Process8
Process4         MYTABLE
Process5         PROCESSX
Process6         MYTABLE
Process7         MYTABLE
Process8         Process9         
Process9         Process10
Process10        MYTABLE
Process11        MYTABLE
Process12        MYTABLE
```

I want the below results

```
Runing_process   PROCESS_Reference

Parent_process   MYTABLE
Process1         MYTABLE
Process4         MYTABLE
Process10        MYTABLE
```

I want to get the PROCESS_Reference that have the name `MYTABLE` related to the Parent_process, for example `Process4` was ran from `Process3`, and `process3` was ran from `Process2` which was ran from `parent_process`.

I tried the below , the select is bit ugly and it will not get all the levels.

```
select *  from table u where u.Runing_process in(
select Runing_process  from table u where u.Runing_process in(
select d.PROCESS_Reference from table d where d.Runing_process ='Parent_process'
)
union all
select PROCESS_Reference  from table u where u.Runing_process in(
select d.PROCESS_Reference from table d where d.Runing_process ='Parent_process'
))
```

Comment: Look at using a recursive cte.

Comment: Your output makes no sense to me at all. Why are 6, 7, 11 and 12 not returned? What is different about 1, 4 and 10?

Comment: @SeanLange as I explained because process 6 was not called from other process that related to parent_process. IF process 6 was called from process4 then it will be returned with the result , because process4 is chained with process 3 and process 2 chained with parent_process .. understand me ?

Comment: Your example is so watered down it is really hard to follow. But a typical recursive cte should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM (VALUES
('Parent_process','Process1'), ('Parent_process','Process2'), ('Parent_process','MYTABLE'),
('Process1','MYTABLE'), ('Process2','Process3'), ('Process2','Process4'),
('Process3','Process8'), ('Process4','MYTABLE'), ('Process5','PROCESSX'),
('Process6','MYTABLE'), ('Process7','MYTABLE'), ('Process8','Process9'),
('Process9','Process10'), ('Process10','MYTABLE'), ('Process11','MYTABLE'),
('Process12','MYTABLE')) AS a(Runing_process,PROCESS_Reference)

;WITH Rec AS (
    SELECT Runing_process, PROCESS_Reference FROM #t
    WHERE Runing_process = 'Parent_process'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Runing_process, r.PROCESS_Reference
    FROM #t AS r
    INNER JOIN Rec AS c ON r.Runing_process = c.PROCESS_Reference
)
SELECT * FROM Rec WHERE PROCESS_Reference = 'MYTABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

the below should work to achieve what you want;

```
    SELECT Runing_process, PROCESS_Reference
    FROM dbo.TestName
    WHERE Runing_process = 'Parent_process'
    AND PROCESS_Reference = 'MyTable'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Runing_process, PROCESS_Reference
    FROM dbo.TestName
    WHERE Runing_process IN ( SELECT DISTINCT PROCESS_Reference
                              FROM dbo.TestName)
    AND PROCESS_Reference = 'MyTable'
```